# Security Headers in htaccess Don't Work

Tags: php, htaccess, security

We have an issue on our server when our Security Headers are not working. We added the following to our htaccess file after installing Craft CMS: -

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOWALL
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
    Header always set Referrer-Policy no-referrer
</IfModule>
```

These settings worked on our previous CMS which was completely developed in house. We have recently upgraded our server to PHP 7 and Apache 2.4. We have been using https://securityheaders.io to check our results.

Any help trying to get this to work would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming mod_headers is installed & active? Otherwhise I can't say why the .htaccess rules are not applied (devOps is not my forte) but you could set them through the twig template.

See [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/header) for the tag to use. Basically it comes down to something like this (untested):

```
{% header 'X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"' %}
{% header 'X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff' %}
{% header 'X-Frame-Options ALLOWALL' %}
{% header 'Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"' %}
{% header 'Referrer-Policy no-referrer' %}
```

You can make those in a block and just include the block on all the relevant pages.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a server config issue than a Craft one.

Craft does set a [few of those headers from PHP](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/web/WebApp.php#L181-L186), but only for Control Panel requests.  It's completely hands-off on the front-end of your site assuming that you'll set whatever headers you want.

As [Michael said](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/21223/57), make sure that mod_headers is installed and make sure that nothing else in your `.htaccess` or any other `.htaccess` files are interfering. I'd also make sure that something like mod_security or Suhosin is also not interfering.

Answer (score -3):

For Apache 2.4, please configure in httpd.conf without mod_headers

.
.
.

Comment: Welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange, SFA! Would you mind elaborating on your answer? It seems like you're recommending a solution that would come with significant drawbacks, but it's hard to tell without any justification for why this should be considered.